# Android: Incomplete image with glReadPixels on Adreno 530 GPU

Tags: android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, glreadpixels

Has anyone experienced something similar or can point to the where the issue might be in the code below? For some reason transparent "dots" appear in the screenshot. It's not all frames maybe every second.

[image: Issue]

I'm seeing some weird behaviour with the Adreno 530 GPU (LG G6, Google Pixel), other GPUs work fine. I think there's some threading issues, because it works fine on the main thread. Here's the deal.

I have a native Android plugin that takes screenshot of a Unity project (OpenGLES3). The OpenGL context is copied from Unity in a background thread. The constructor looks like this:

```
    this.handlerThread = new HandlerThread("UnityScreenCapture");
    this.handlerThread.start();
    this.handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());

    final EGLContext currentContext = EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext();
    final EGLDisplay currentDisplay = EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay();

    final int[] eglContextClientVersion = new int[1];
    eglQueryContext(currentDisplay,
            currentContext,
            EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
            eglContextClientVersion,
            0
    );

    this.handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

            final int[] version = new int[2];
            eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1);

            int[] configAttributes = {EGL14.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE,
                    EGL14.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
                    EGL14.EGL_LEVEL,
                    0,
                    EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,
                    EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                    EGL14.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,
                    EGL14.EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
                    EGL14.EGL_NONE};
            final EGLConfig[] eglConfigs = new EGLConfig[1];
            final int[] numConfig = new int[1];
            eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configAttributes, 0, eglConfigs, 0, 1, numConfig, 0);

            final EGLConfig eglConfig = eglConfigs[0];

            int[] surfaceAttributes = {EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, 1, EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, 1, EGL14.EGL_NONE};
            EGLSurface eglSurface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDisplay,
                    eglConfig,
                    surfaceAttributes,
                    0
            );

            int[] contextAttributes = {EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
                    eglContextClientVersion[0],
                    EGL14.EGL_NONE};

            final EGLContext eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay,
                    eglConfig,
                    currentContext,
                    contextAttributes,
                    0
            );

            eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);
        }
    });
}
```

Then when I'm taking a screenshot I call the same background thread to avoid blocking main:

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setBytes(native_readFrame(frame.getBytes()));
            callback.capturedFrame(frame);
        }
    });
```

native_readFrame looks like this (stripped down):

```
mcluint texture = capture_context->texture;

if (capture_context->framebuffer == 0) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    mcluint framebuffer;

    // Generate framebuffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);

    // Bind texture to framebuffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    capture_context->framebuffer = framebuffer;
}

int width = capture_context->width;
int height = capture_context->height;
rect_t crop = capture_context->crop;

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, capture_context->framebuffer);

mclbyte *pixels = NULL;
if (dst != NULL) {
    pixels = *dst;
} else {
    pixels = (mclbyte *) malloc(crop.width * crop.height * sizeof(mclbyte) * 4);
}

glReadPixels(crop.x, crop.y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             pixels);

if (length != NULL) {
    *length = crop.width * crop.height * sizeof(mclbyte) * 4;
}
return pixels;
```

**UPDATE**
If I call glFinish() on main right before readFrame, it works. But glFinish is a heavy operation blocking the main thread for 10ms which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the frame is already rendered before reading it out.

Opengl has a client-server architecture. The cpu gives the gpu draw calls which will will not block the cpu thread. The gpu will schedule these calls to be executed later, but you can force them to start executing immediately if you call glFlush(). glFinish() on the other hand makes the client side wait in addition to calling a glFlush().

Since the request to the gpu might come from different threads, I suggest you to take a look at how to sync them:

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object